# ERRNO 5 Input/Output Error When Installing Juno

Tags: system-installation, release-juno, usb-drive

I recently tried to install Elementary OS Juno onto my computer, and kept getting this error, `ERRNO 5 Input/Output Error` during the installation.

It says along with the error popup that it could be due to a faulty CD/DVD disk/drive.

I ran the installer through a 32GB USB drive that I had used to install Kali Linux on right before trying to install Elementary OS on it, as well as Lubuntu and KDE Neon after giving up on it.

The flash drive worked fine when installing everything except Elementary OS.

- I searched all over the web to find solutions, all of which I tried.
- I checked the SHA-256sum, and it matched.
- I tried reflashing the Bootable USB multiple times, sometimes with UNetBootin and others with Etcher, and no luck either times.
- I tried changing the partitions to ext3, no luck.
- I tried shrinking the EFI partition to under 256MB, no luck. Nothing seems to be working.

I know it's not the flash drive because I used it to install multiple other distros before and after trying to install Elementary OS, and those all installed with no issues whatsoever.

I did that by downloading the ISOs for Lubuntu onto the live installation of Elementary OS and then accidentally flashing it onto the flash drive I was running the live boot on, and then I installed that, then flashed KDE Neon onto the flash drive and installing that.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as **Answer** that helped solving your problem. If you have solved this on your own, please write it down as answer and mark it so.

Answer (score 1):

I found this steps here

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1207755&page=2&p=7582893#post7582893

1. **Boot** from the live CD
2. Choose to **try** elementaryOS
3. **Open** a terminal window
4. **Write** and **execute**: `ubiquity --no-migration-assistant`
5. **Install** without problems

AFAIK elementaryOS still uses Ubiquity installer

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't recognize the command. I'm now trying to reflash the ISO onto a different flash drive using Rufus in DD mode like someone suggested on the Ubuntu forums. I'll update this if it works.

Comment: then wait me a second I need to check which installer now Juno has, probably the same but different command because if isn't `ubiquity` is a fork of it

Comment: Okay, I FINALLY fixed it! The problem was that I needed to flash it in DD mode like I said earlier. I did that and it installed fine, but after that there was one problem. When I logged in, everything showed up, but then when I clicked on a program, it went black for a second, and it logged me out. When I logged back in again, nothing but the wallpaper and the mouse cursor showed up. So the problem for that was that I needed to install the NVIDIA drivers, so I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F2, which brought up a terminal, and then followed the instructions from this guide. https://bit.ly/2P8gGbe

Comment: Then it worked fine.

Comment: Cool, now write it down as answer for your own an accept your own answer that way this post will be done/green. Because you solved your question :P. GL

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to [Connor](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/16523/connor-finley), but I am adding this as an answer because I came here after encountering this problem and would like others to know it has been solved. Peace!

> According to Connor's comment in an answer posted bellow,
>
> > Okay, I FINALLY fixed it! The problem was that I needed to flash it in DD mode like I said earlier. I did that and it installed fine, but after that there was one problem. When I logged in, everything showed up, but then when I clicked on a program, it went black for a second, and it logged me out. When I logged back in again, nothing but the wallpaper and the mouse cursor showed up. So the problem for that was that I needed to install the NVIDIA drivers, so I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F2, which brought up a terminal, and then followed the instructions from this guide. [bit.ly/2P8gGbe](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I had the same issue with Elementary 5.1(Hera) and tried the following things.

- Downloading the iso again
- Did hash check and found it's ok
- Recreate the USB using Unetbootin, then Startup disk creator
- ubiquity --no-migration-assistant
- Restructuring partitions

But none of the above worked.

**Finaly what worked was, i wrote the image to a DVD using Brasero and tried. It worked like charm.**